# Express.js redirect causes 'failed to load resources' error in Chrome console

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am build an app in Node.js using Express.js.

I find when using `res.redirect('/')` the Chrome console is returning the following errors on my static files:

[image]

This only occurs when I use `res.redirect` not when using `res.render` or `res.send`. This problem does not occur on Safari, only Chrome.

This is my app.js file where I set the static directory:

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const errorController = require('./controllers/error');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);

app.use(errorController.get404);

app.listen(3000);
```

This is an example of one of the controllers with the redirect in it:

```
exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
   const {id} = req.body
   Product.findById(id, product => {
      Cart.addProduct(id, +product.price)
   })
   res.redirect('/cart')
}
```

This is the head of my HTML for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><%= pageTitle %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Note: I'm using EJS and including the head as part of the ejs file as this example:

```
<%- include('../includes/head.ejs') %>
    </head>

    <body>
        <%- include('../includes/navigation.ejs') %>
        <%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
```

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? Because I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you are using "**nodemon**" or not. But In my case, it's due to "**nodemon**".

Because I was saving my data in a JSON file named as ***(data/products.json)*** and whenever I used to add a new data to it "**nodemon**" gets restarted.

You can run your main file normally like.

```
node app.js
```

or you can add the following configuration in the **package.json** file.

```
"nodemonConfig": {        
    "ignore": ["data/products.json"]  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**express.static(root, [options])**

> The root argument specifies the root directory from which to serve
> static assets. The function determines the file to serve by combining
> req.url with the provided root directory.

Change the middleware to look like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Hi Luis thanks heaps for the response. 

I changed the middleware as indicated, but I'm afraid it it still returning the same error in the Chrome console. Only happening when res.redirect is called.

Comment: Could you try to start chrome in incognito mode, disabling your extensions and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Error continues to occur in incognito mode. It's a weird one this one.

Comment: Have you disabled your extensions too? Could you provide us the new Error?